# Detecting Chrome browser with AJAX

Tags: .net, browser, google-chrome

I use `Sys.Browser.name` for borwser detection, but Chrome detected as safari.

Comment: Sidenote: Detecting the browser by name should only be done for statistics, but not to determine the behavior of the website. For the website behavior use feature detection.

Comment: +1 to CodeInChaos, excellent point.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search turned up this page: http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript

Basically, read the full user-agent and find the string 'chrome':

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're checking for "webkit", which happens to exist in both safari and chrome.

> **Chrome**
>
> 5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10
>
> ---
>
> **Safari**
>
> 5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.3 Safari/533.19.4

Ensure that it is webkit (as I guess you're doing already) and also check for "`Chrome`".

**Edit:** What exactly is your code platform? `Sys.Browser.Name` doesn't sound familiar to me. Also, what is the exact code you're using?

**Edit 2:** You still didn't mention what code you are using. **1.** I don't have .NET here. **2.** I can't code it up for you right now. **3.** I need to see you doing the comparison. **4.** I largely forgot how C#/VB works, so seeing your code will great help out.

*Without more info, I can't help more than that, sorry.*

Comment: Sys.Browser.Name is a field of AJAX's Sys.Browser class 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679109(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: That's a bit confusing. The real platform you are using is .NET, not AJAX, in fact, the browser name doesn't concern AJAX one bit. Edit: I retagged post for your convenience.